# Add php within a string

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to take

```
$imgsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/s.php?strings=';
```

and add `the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4)` after strings.

How do I go about doing that?

```
$imgsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/titles.php?strings=' . the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4);
```

doesn't seem to output a single URL.

Comment: What does `the_content_rss` output?

Comment: If you're trying to make this an image's URL, php's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) may be your answer.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have issues, unless your functions are returning unexpected values

Comment: `<img src="http://url.com/s.php?strings=<?php the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4); ?>" />` Works as expected. But, within PHP as said above, like, `$imgsrc = $match[1]; } else { $imgsrc ='http://url.com/s.php?strings=' . php the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4);` doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you should understand is

> String concatenation requires functions that **return** value not output/echo them.

So, make sure `get_template_directory_uri()` and `the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4);` returns a value instead of displaying them. If both functions return a value, the URL should be build as expected.

Comment: `<img src="http://url.com/s.php?strings=<?php the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4); ?>" />`Works as expected. But, within PHP as said above, like, `$imgsrc = $match[1]; } else { $imgsrc ='http://url.com/s.php?strings=' . php the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 4);` doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Brown, Your syntax in that code snippet in the comment is horrible. You've got a broken `if/else` and why the `php` part of ` . php the_content_rss`? Also, re-read the answer with special attention to the highlighted part about needing a `return` value.